# Autodesk Forge - How to allow selecting markups without being in edit mode

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

We are trying to build functionality similar to the 2D viewer inside Autodesk BIM360. There, it is possible to see all svgs at the same time, and also select individual svgs. Once an svg has been selected you can enter edit mode for that svg layer by clicking a button.

Here is a video showing the functionality: https://www.screencast.com/t/YXykjI5REG

We are struggling to find a way to allow the user to select a particular layer by clicking one of the markups in that layer.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

The viewer includes two extensions for markups, `Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsCore` and `Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsGui`. The latter should provide some basic infrastructure for selecting and manipulating existing markup, but the BIM360 product probably implements the UI interactions in their own way, and that implementation isn't available.

With that said, the markups are basically just an SVG overlay, so you could implement your own layering, e.g., by placing SVG elements into [group](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/g) elements.